# Members of the sequence greater than 1 less than N

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose N is a positive integer. How many decreasing
integer sequences are there such that members of the
sequence are greater than 1 but less than N… 
I have tried to come up with an expression for this problem.
Do i need to look into prime numbers? excluding 1 and the number makes me think so...

Comment: Have you tried this for small values of $N$? Like $N=2,3,4,5$? Having numerical evidence can help you guess the answer, and then you have a better chance of proving it.

Comment: I have, but with only smaller integers, e.g. 8, I’m decreasing the number by 1, until I have the last member of the sequence as  3-1 > 1. My dilemma is what if N is much larger and I want to decrease it in multiples of N??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $I_k$ be  the number of such sequences with $k$ terms. For example $I_{N-2}=1.$  Then the number of such sequences is 
$$
I_{N-2}+I_{N-3}+\cdots+I_{1}
$$

It is clear that  $I_{N-3}={N-2 \choose 1},$ $I_{N-3}={N-2 \choose 2}$ and so on. Thus 
$$
I_{N-2}+I_{N-3}+\cdots+I_{1}=\sum_{i=0}^{N-3}{N-2 \choose i}=2^{N-2}-1.
$$

Comment: Thanks for responding promptly...what I don’t understand is the summation part, if I had to use a general formula, would I then just have N-i as my upper limit and 2^N-i - 1 to the right of the equal sign?

Comment: what is your calculation for $N=2,3,4?$

Comment: Given your expression above, when N=2 and N=3 then the restriction wouldn’t hold, because I get 0, so zero members?!?!  So N has to be > than 3 then...N=4 gives one member

Comment: I think I see why (I sub N-3) implies N>3...I get it now...Thank you so much Leox!!

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP has been given a fully-formed answer, I'd like to point out an argument that gets to the final form without passing through a summation.

We can equivalently solve for the number of sequences with members between $1$ and $N-2$ inclusive, by subtracting $1$ from each member.

However, notice that the decreasing condition implies that no two members are the same, and moreover if I tell you the set of members then in fact the sequence is entirely determined. Moreover, every subset of $\{1,2,\dots, N-2\}$ corresponds to a sequence of the desired type, *except* for the empty set, since we need at least one term.

Therefore, the number of sequences of the desired type is equal to the number of nonempty subsets of $\{1,2,\dots, N-2\}$, which is $2^{N-2}-1$.

Comment: and because we are only looking at the decreasing sequence members, that has no bearing on how N is decreasing... and yes with the condition/restriction given in the question, only members >1 but less than N would discard the empty set... I appreciate both contributions. The one Leox gives breaks it down step by step, and that helped me understand the final formula...

Comment: You cannot give best answer to two people. If you found Leox's answer more helpful, you should give it to em.

Comment: Oh, I wondered why his ‘unchecked’ both contributions were helpful to me...I’m new to the site